# MVC2 to MVC upgrade error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, namespaces, upgrade

I keep on getting: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

I have installed MVC3 and MS .Net Framework 4 and want to upgrade a solution that was written in MVC1 and upgraded to MVC2. I would now like to upgrade to MVC3 but keep on getting the above error. I suspect that it is the reference that I have to System.web, if I view the properties of it in VS2010 I can see that it is still pointing to Version 2.0

I delete the reference and add a new one to the  system.web.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0 but when I right click on the reference in VS2010 solution explorer to view the properties it still points to the version 2 in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll

I did add the something new to VS2010, I think it was a Powertools pack and adding the reference looks different, could it be that? I did add the ref to the new system.web.mvc dll and that shows correctly. Just as a note, I did the upgrade by hand as per the MS notes and tried the upgrade tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation was solid on the upgrade. The problem was with the Powertools and once I un-installed it I could add the reference again.

Answer (score 1):

Try following the [upgrade steps](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#upgrading). Also there's a [project upgrade tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx) you may checkout.